# trying to walk a tree, always getting no results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a n-tier affiliate system which I'm trying to walk so I can get counts and lists of affiliates' sub-affiliates. I have, among other fields, an "id" and "affiliate_id" on each entry.

```
def find_affiliates_under(affid)
  affs=Array.new
  Affiliate.find(:all, :conditions => "affiliate_id = " + affid.to_s, :select => :id).each do |a|
    affs.concat(find_affiliates_under(a.id))
  end
return affs.uniq
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Would appreciate a pointer from someone with more experience with Ruby
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you the `id`'s or are you also looking for the nested objects themselves.  By placing a `select => :id` option, you're only going to select the `id` of each object.

May I recommend taking a look at [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set).  I think it will achieve what you're trying to do, while saving you some time.

Comment: In this case for example's sake I am just looking to count the children. 

I've seen the acts as tree and nested set plugins, either of them will require data model changes which is something I am unable to do due to the complexity of the application I'm re-engineering.